# Why is a presen participle (using) used here?

Tags: grammar, present-participles

"Combine the following sentences **using** the conjunctions given in the brackets"

Can I use "by using", "use" instead?

Comment: *Use* doesn't work. *By using* is the Microsoft *by*. To me it's unnatural to the point of being wrong, but others may disagree.

Comment: @Minty What is “the Microsoft _by_”? I haven't heard of that before. I agree that adding _by_ would not be quite natural here, where _using_ is basically synonymous with the preposition _with_, but in many slightly different cases where it still retains more of its verbal quality, _by using_ would be perfectly natural to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I've always been very conscious of the grammatical idiosyncrasies of companies like MS, because they get into the grammar checking/policing apps that so many people take to be infallible, creating a danger that a rule made up by MS becomes a de facto rule of English grammar. MS documentation - help files for example, would invariably use *by* in constructions like *do X by using the mouse*, as if to inisist that it was necessary when at best it is pleonastic - so this construction entered my brainsphere as *the MS by*. I hate it.

Answer (score 1):

*using the conjunctions given in the brackets* is an example of a *participle clause*. In particular, a participle clause with *-ing* implies that the action occurs at the same time as the action described by the main clause, e.g.:

> They spent the rest of the journey in silence, looking at each other. 
>   (They were silent *and at the same time* looking at each other)

There's nothing preventing the main clause to be an imperative one, e.g.:

> Open the door slowly, keeping the dog inside. 
>   (Open the door *and at the same time* don't let the dog go outside)

Your sentence is just another example of that:

> Combine the following sentences using the conjunctions given in the brackets. 
>   (Combine the sentences *and at the same time* make sure you only use the conjunctions given in the brackets)

*By* added before the *-ing* form usually implies the *manner* in which some action is performed (*by*=*by means of*), e.g.:

> By using magic, they managed to defeat the old dragon. (They managed to defeat the old dragon by means of magic)

Note that *by* can usually be omitted in this context as well, but sometimes it is necessary to avoid confusion:

> The boy concluded the horses were still in the area by examining the hoofprints.
>
> The boy concluded the horses were still in the area examining the hoofprints. (who examined the hoofprints, the boy or the horses?)

You could argue that your example also describes the *manner* in which the exercise is to be completed. Therefore, using *by* is not an error, though it makes the sentence a bit contrived.

As a final note, the only way *use* can be, well, used in your sentence is by splitting it into two separate instructions:

> Combine the following sentences. Use the conjunctions given in the brackets.